# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar un servicio/ventana de nombre especifico con CMD?

Tags: cmd

muy buenas. Necesito cerrar un proceso de nombre especifico, pero no encuentro ninguna manera para hacerlo con el nombre de la ventana en sí, toda la información que he encontrado es básicamente cerrar todos los procesos del mismo nombre general y eso no me sirve.

[image: NOMBRE DE LA VENTANA]

[image: IMAGEN DE COMANDO REFERENCIAL]

Si cierro CMD obviamente todo se cerrará lo cual no me sirve, quisiera cerrar solo la ventana que tiene una ruta además del run.bat, pero no encuentro forma de detectarlo, todos los servicios llevan el mismo nombre y el PID va cambiando

Answer (score 0):

Puede modificar el archivo por lotes para que use un archivo de bloqueo para continuar operando, insertando comprobaciones entre comandos para la existencia del archivo. Para detener la ejecución del archivo por lotes, simplemente elimine el archivo de bloqueo.

Aquí hay un archivo por lotes de demostración:

```
echo xx > "c:\temp\lockfile"
pause
if not exist "c:\temp\lockfile" goto  exit
pause
del "c:\temp\lockfile"
:exit
```

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve, sino seguimos buscando

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude arreglar, simplemente le di un nombre a la ventana y usé un comando de cierre por nombre de ventana.

```
@echo off
tittle ServerCore
```

Usé este comando para encontrarlo específicamente por su titulo y luego el taskkill para cerrarlo, funciona perfecto.

```
tasklist /V /FI "WindowTitle eq ServerCore*"

taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq ServerCore*" /F
```

Gracias igualmente. :D